# Mantis "Recently modified" changing after user monitors an issue

Tags: mantis

I'm administering a mantis site which has tens of thousands of users and thousands of issues (mostly closed). Mantis will, by default, modify the "Recently Modified" field whenever a user Monitors an issue. I would like to disable this functionality - is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not without modifying the code.

Try commenting out [this line](https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt/blob/release-1.3.0/core/bug_api.php#L1964).